# Issue with writing .csv file with ruby

Tags: ruby, csv

Im learning ruby and i have this issue:
I'm having and issue with writing `. CSV` by a `. Text` file.
That's my Ruby code:

```
require 'csv'

class Plantas <

    Struct.new(:identifier, :code, :lang, :fullname)
  
  end


f = File.open("planta.txt", "r")

f.each_line { |line|

  fields = line.split(',')

  newPlant = Plantas.new


  newPlant.identifier = fields[0].tr_s('"', '').strip
  newPlant.code = fields[2].tr_s('"', '').strip
  newPlant.lang = fields[3].tr_s('"', '').strip
  newPlant.fullname = fields[10].tr_s('"', '').strip


    str = "#{newPlant.identifier} #{newPlant.code} #{newPlant.lang} #{newPlant.fullname}" #linies a imprimir
    #puts str

        CSV.open("plantas.csv", "w") do |csv|
            csv << [str]
end
}
```

And that's my `.txt` file:

```
"identifier","datatype","code","lang","langno","preferred","status","creation","modification","country","fullname","authority","shortname"
"N1952","PFL","LEECO","la","1","0","N","06/06/2000","09/03/2010","","Leea coccinea non","Planchon","Leea coccinea non"
"N51170","PFL","CAWUR","en","4","0","N","28/02/2002","24/08/2010","","Toddy palm","","Toddy palm"
```

And that's the output on the `.csv`

```
N51170 CAWUR en Toddy palm
```

Just write the last line instead of all the lines printed in the `.txt`
I want that the code print me all the lines in the file.csv without ' " ' and ','

Could someone help? Thanks!

Comment: Do the `CSV.open` bit outside of your `each_line` loop

Comment: What you're writing doesn't really qualify as a CSV file. Your input on the other hand is in CSV format. Maybe it would make more sense to read the input via `CSV.parse` and to write the output manually via `File` calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are very close!

Given:

```
% cat file.csv
"identifier","datatype","code","lang","langno","preferred","status","creation","modification","country","fullname","authority","shortname"
"N1952","PFL","LEECO","la","1","0","N","06/06/2000","09/03/2010","","Leea coccinea non","Planchon","Leea coccinea non"
"N51170","PFL","CAWUR","en","4","0","N","28/02/2002","24/08/2010","","Toddy palm","","Toddy palm"
```

You can modify your code this way:

```
require 'csv'

class Plantas <
        Struct.new(:identifier, :code, :lang, :fullname)
    end
    
f_in = File.open("/tmp/file.csv", "r")
f_out=CSV.open("/tmp/plantas.csv", "w")

f_in.each_line { |line|
    
    fields = line.split(',')
    
    newPlant = Plantas.new
    
    newPlant.identifier = fields[0].tr_s('"', '').strip
    newPlant.code = fields[2].tr_s('"', '').strip
    newPlant.lang = fields[3].tr_s('"', '').strip
    newPlant.fullname = fields[10].tr_s('"', '').strip
    
        str = "#{newPlant.identifier} #{newPlant.code} #{newPlant.lang} #{newPlant.fullname}" #linies a imprimir
        f_out << [str]
}
```

Which results in this:

```
% cat plantas.csv
identifier code lang fullname
N1952 LEECO la Leea coccinea non
N51170 CAWUR en Toddy palm
```

**Even Better** you can correctly treat the input as CSV as read it as such:

```
# same top part, then:

f_in = CSV.open("/tmp/file.csv", "r")
f_out=CSV.open("/tmp/plantas.csv", "w")

f_in.each { |row|
    
    newPlant = Plantas.new
    
    newPlant.identifier = row[0]
    newPlant.code = row[2]
    newPlant.lang = row[3]
    newPlant.fullname = row[10]
    
    str = "#{newPlant.identifier} #{newPlant.code} #{newPlant.lang} #{newPlant.fullname}" #linies a imprimir
    puts str
    f_out << [str]
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That worked for me! Hope this answer helps more people.